# Does AWS RDS Oracle 11G support restore points with GUARANTEE FLASHBACK DATABASE?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, database-backups

I have Oracle 11G SE1 on AWS RDS.

I'm trying to do :

```
CREATE RESTORE POINT RestorePointName GUARANTEE FLASHBACK DATABASE;
```

and I'm getting :

```
Error at Command Line:1 Column:1
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to change the current username or password
           without the appropriate privilege. This error also occurs if
           attempting to install a database without the necessary operating
           system privileges.
           When Trusted Oracle is configure in DBMS MAC, this error may occur
           if the user was granted the necessary privilege at a higher label
           than the current login.
*Action:   Ask the database administrator to perform the operation or grant
           the required privileges.
           For Trusted Oracle users getting this error although granted the
           the appropriate privilege at a higher label, ask the database
           administrator to regrant the privilege at the appropriate label.
```

I'm logged in as the admin user.